# É possível um loop com um jump variável?

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um loop com jump variável. Por exemplo, no ciclos dispares o jump seria 2 e nos ciclos pares os ciclos seriam 4.

Tentei faze-lo com o operator ternário do Python `a if True else b`, mas não funciona porque a função range não muda durante o loop.

```
for j in range(i, len(message), small if odd else big):
    print(j)
```

Comment: Você adicionou a tag `encriptação` na pergunta, isso que você está tentando fazer tem a ver com criptografia? Em que sentido? Se possível, por favor contextualize mais.

Comment: Pra Rail Fence vai precisar de um pouco mais do que um loop. Talvez 2 loops entrelaçados seja melhor, o de fora controlando o offset dos passos do de dentro. Quanto mais na "beirada", maior o offset, que normaliza no meio.

Comment: Hehe estou detectando um ["Problema XY"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215)... :P Esse é meu primeiro contato com o Rail Fence, mas à primeira vista me parece que há maneiras melhores de implementá-lo. Posso dar uma sugestão? Crie uma função ou fórmula para escolher a linha certa dada a letra na mensagem (i.e. que faça esse zigue-zague entre as linhas). Depois disso, para cada letra você a coloca na linha certa, primeiro aumentando-a com pontos até ela ter o tamanho certo. Depois concatene as linhas e elimine os pontos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode alternar o passo na hora de usar a variável:

```
for j in range(1, 20, 3):
    print(j if j & 1 else j + 1)
```

Saída:

```
1
5
7
11
13
17
19
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oVdvQd)**.

Se quiser ajustar o momento em que os passos ocorrem, pode trocar o `j + 1` por `j - 1`, ou então trocar o `+ 1` do lado do if, ou mesmo mudar o offset inicial, vai do caso concreto.

Comment: +1 pois está no caminho certo, mas repare que a ordem dos jumps será diferente se o valor inicial for par ou ímpar.

Comment: @mgibsonbr realmente falta um pouco mais de informação na pergunta sobre o caso real, aí vai de ajustar; Deixei um comment neste sentido ao final. Se o OP puser mais detalhes, edito a resposta. De qq forma, a observação é válida.

Answer (score 3):

[A resposta do Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37427/215) me parece ser a única maneira correta, ainda que alguns detalhes me escapem. Sua sequência é:

```
         {  i,          se n == 0;
seq(n) = {  seq(n-1)+2, se n % 2 == 1;
         {  seq(n-1)+4, se n % 2 == 0.
```

Ou seja, `i`, `i+2`, `i+6`, `i+8`, `i+12`, ... Essa sequência pode ser simplificada para:

```
i + 0*3 - 0,
i + 1*3 - 1,
i + 2*3 - 0,
i + 3*3 - 1,
i + 4*3 - 0,
...
```

Onde cada termo, então, é igual a `i + n*3 - n%2`. i.e. "vá de 3 em 3, subtraindo 1 nos termos ímpares". Uma maneira de implementar isso seria:

```
for j in [i + n*3 - n%2 for n in range(0, limite_superior)]:
    print(j)
```

Onde `limite_superior` é o `n`, tal que `i + n*3 - n%2 >= len(message)`, i.e.:

```
n*3 - n%2 >= len(message) - i
n*3 >= len(message) - i + n%2
n >= (len(message) - i + n%2)/3
```

Mas a solução do Bacco é mais simples e elegante - apenas preste atenção na diferença entre os `i`s pares e ímpares (num caso o primeiro desvio será `2`, no outro será `4`).